# -What if $V$ is infinite dimensional? What if $A$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to another vector space $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$  is one-to-one; then , $\ker A= \{0\}. \tag1$

i know  that if $A$ be a linear transformation on a finite dimensional vector space $V.$ then  this $(1)$ will  true.

## Now  my question  is  that

-What if $V$ is infinite dimensional? What if $A$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to another vector space $W$?

Comment: Any linear transformation will be one to one if and only if its kernel is $\{0\}$

Comment: thanks @Omnomnomnom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is not one-to-one then there are vectors $\vec x \ne \vec y$ with $A\vec x = A\vec y.$ By a simple application of the definition of linearity, that implies $\vec x - \vec y$ is in the kernel of $A$ and $\vec x-\vec y\ne\vec 0.$

Coversely, if $\vec 0 \ne \vec z\in\ker A,$ then $A\vec0=A\vec z$ even though $\vec0\ne\vec z,$ so $A$ is not one-to-one.

So linearity is all you need here.